# select current element from div where getting data from backend Django

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

I want to implement the one algorithm
I am getting the ID data from the backend in html.

html file

```
{% for question in questions %}
                        <div class="question col-lg-11">
                            <div class="name col-lg-2 ">
                                {{ question.name }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="points slider col-lg-4">

                            </div>
                             <input type="text" id="value" class="amount col-lg-1" value="10" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
                             <div class="Id_of_metric">
                                {{ question.id }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="meta col-lg-4">
                                {{ question.details }}
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <br />
                    {% endfor %}
```

I want to get the ID in javascript to check the condition.
i tried the way

```
function deside(){
        number=$(this).find('.Id_of_metric').text();
        console.log(number);
    }
```

but i am not getting the correct ID
the result i am getting is 2 and then it increasing as i slide on slider.
I want to get the id for perticular field, there are 10 fields in django backend.
So i want to get id dynamically.
And anothe problem is that when slide on the slider that much time deside() function get executed. i want to get that function executed first time only.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You have  `<div id="Id_of_metric">` which should be  `<div class="Id_of_metric">`

Comment: still i am facing the same problem.